# Connection state with libmicrohttpd and http 102

Tags: c, http, webserver

What I am trying to achieved is:

1. Send http 102 to client who requested somedoc.html
2. Some processing on the side including out of band authentication
3. If authenticated, send response built from somedoc.html, otherwise generic not auth message

I'm having a failure of understanding somewhere, in that  I cannot seem to figure out how to send the 102 and save the connection details so that I can forward the response in step 3.  I had thought I could queue a response then either enter a wait loop or suspend the connection, but as far as I can tell I have to return from the `MHD_AcceptPolicyCallback` for the response to be sent, then I cannot figure out how to get back to the connection.  I have looked at the request completed call back but this still results in the 102 not being sent.

I really can't figure out a process to achieve these steps from the examples or the manual and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP standards doesn't define response code `102`.
See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6 
and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1

HTTP protocol use request-response logic. If you already responded to some request then you can't add another response later to the same request.

Comment: I asked this question on the mailing and got a similar response, so sorry if this is the same person but:  It was defined in RFC 2518, which was updated/obsoleted by RFC 4918 for WebDAV.  Granted they removed http 102 from the specification (due to a lack of implementation) and advise that its IANA registration should continue to refer to RDF2518. It is implemented in libmicrohttpd as MHD_HTTP_PROCESSING.  Using the MHD_HTTP_PROCESSING code requires some mechanism to first send a response with this code and then send a final response.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with the developer, the 102 status code was defined "for completeness"; however, no attempt has been made to implement the required functionality to actually be able to use this status code in a meaningful way on a server developed with the libmicrohttpd library.